# how do i go about debugging this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, localhost

I just recently started this ruby on rails tutorial to kick off my new adventure into a new language and following the tutorial I got stuck. After I edited my index.html.erb file to what the tutorial was doing my localhost server gave me a error

```
**Routing Error**
No route matches [GET] "/"
```

I honestly do not know how to debug this

This is what's in the index file

```
<% @snippet.each do |snippet| %>
<h2><%= snippet.title %></h2>
<%end%>
```

And for my routes:

```
Josegomez::Application.routes.draw do
resources :snippets
```

Here is the video I been following it requires you to be a member though but I figured most would ask about it http://tutsplus.com/tutorial/how-to-deploy-your-first-rails-app/

Here is what I got when I typed rake routes

```
Jose-Gomezs-MacBook-Pro:josegomez josegomez$ rake routes
    snippets GET    /snippets(.:format)          snippets#index
             POST   /snippets(.:format)          snippets#create
 new_snippet GET    /snippets/new(.:format)      snippets#new
edit_snippet GET    /snippets/:id/edit(.:format) snippets#edit
     snippet GET    /snippets/:id(.:format)      snippets#show
             PUT    /snippets/:id(.:format)      snippets#update
             DELETE /snippets/:id(.:format)      snippets#destroy
```

Hey may be using a older version...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need route to root

Add this to routes.rb

```
root :to => 'snippets#index'
```